# Export statistics from Watson Assistant into excel file

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Is there any way to export data such as "**Total conversations**", "**Avg. msg. per conversation**", and number of Entities that were mentioned in the conversation from IBM Watson Assistant into excel file? This refers to the **Improve** section of the workbench where the average number of messages per conversation and other data is shown.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with some effort. [IBM Watson Assistant provides an API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl) to work with the objects in a workspace and has also some cross-workspace methods. Included is a [log API to retrieve per workspace or cross-workspace logs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#logs-api). The returned data is in JSON format. There are parameters to filter the data. The rest is basically to extract the necessary data for those statistics and import it to Excel. There are many JSON to CSV converters to bring the data into columnar format.